# How can alien in human suit cry?

Tags: plot-explanation, cocoon

In Cocoon (1985), Walter cries when his friend (alien) dies in the cocoon.

[image]

Actually Walter is also an alien with human skin.

How does an alien in a human suit get tears?

Comment: Plot hole? maybe it got from the suit (since it has hairs, skin, who knows what else it can get from the suit?) I don't think it was explicitly explained in the movie.

Comment: I'm voting plot hole too, but I still gave this question a thumbs up. It wasn't exactly a "hard science" movie, so the science behind the human suits probably isn't very scientific.